# Using If else staments in constraints for MIP solver OR-tools in Python

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I'm using the MIP Solver of OR Tools for Python and I have stubled on a problem to declare a constraint. The constraint in question, which is represented by the image below, is about the proportion between male and female Animals (a):

[image: constraint description]

So far I tried two ways to do this:

```
for t in times:
  solver.Add(
      solver.Sum(
          if a in animais_male:
            [n_animals[(a,t)]*sell[(a, t)]
           elif a in animais_female:
             -proportion_max*n_animals[(a,t)]*sell[(a, t)]
             for a in animais
             ]) <= 0)
```

This one returned this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-20-95a1db1c4418>", line 5
    if a in animals_male:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And the other solution I tried was:

```
for t in dias_considerados:
  solver.Add(
      solver.Sum(
          [n_animals[(a,t)]*sell[(a, t)]
           for a in animals_male
           -proportion_max*n_animals[(a,t)]*sell[(a, t)]
            for a in animals_female
            ]) <= 0)
```

And I got this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-2dfedfd19682> in <module>()
      4           [n_animals[(a,t)]*sell[(a, t)]
      5            for a in animals_male
----> 6            -proportion_max*n_animals[(a,t)]*sell[(a, t)]
      7             for a in animals_female
      8             ]) <= 0)

TypeError: 'SumArray' object is not iterable
```

`n_animals[(a,t)]` is the number of animals, represented as n_(a,t) in the image and `sell[(a,t)]` is the I_(a,t) binary decision variable in the image.

So if anyone could help I would apreciate! If there is a need for me to better explain my situation I am available to do so.

Comment: Overall what I want is a constraint that establishs that for every male animals that I have, I can have, maximum, the proportion (proportion_max in the code and the image) amount of female animals, for every day (t) in the times set

Comment: look for linearization of if then else in the mip community. It will involve big-M formulations.

Comment: You cannot do an if directly in a sum. But you can do a list comprehension (with an if) inside a sum. Obviously only if the if is exogenous (as seems to be the case here).